# Website for Elsevier Encyclopedia (or glossary)?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I'm quite positive that I saw before an encyclopedia (more accurately, dictionary/glossary) on Elsevier website. I remember I looked up the definition of a hyperplane there, few months ago. But I can't find it through Google anymore.

Does anyone know the link?

Comment: Even if you aren't confusing Elsevier with Springer, this is quite an impressive reference: [The Springer Online Encyclopaedia of Mathematics](http://eom.springer.de/).

Comment: As a side note of interest: http://www.latexsearch.com/

Comment: @Rahul Exactly, I was confusing them. Thanks!

Comment: Shall I post that as an answer so you can mark the question as answered? Otherwise the software will keep bumping it up to the front page periodically.

Comment: @Rahul yes, please do that. It's a shame that there is no easy option for closing a topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing Elsevier with Springer. [The Springer Online Encyclopaedia of Mathematics](http://eom.springer.de/) is quite an impressive reference.

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken. The site has now moved to [encyclopediaofmath.org](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Main_Page). Furthermore, the publisher has switched from Springer Verlag to EMS Press.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for doesn't seem to exist (if you go to Elsevier site and type any combination of what you are looking for, like math glossary, you don't get any relevant answers).

You might want to check Wolfram Mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/

Comment: Sure it doesn't exist. As Rahul indicated above, I was confusing Elsevier with Springer.